# constant expression function in c++98

Tags: c++, templates, c++98, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

I have following problem with c++98 constant expressions.
Here is an example for an template struct.. which will receive the size at compile time..

Is it somehow possible to get this size as constant expression without c++11 constexpr?
Take a look at GetCount()...

```
    template <typename ValueType, UInt32 size>
    struct FixedArray
    {
       ValueType mArr[size > 0 ? size : 1];
       UInt32 GetCount() const { return size; }

      ...
      other code
      ..
    }
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
FixedArray<int , 10> a;
FixedArray<int , a.GetSize()> b;
```

Edit:

I couldn't find a way for C++ 98, seems like it isn't possible at all.

Comment: You can map numbers to types. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Int-To-Type

Comment: People are jumping on board C++17 now. Why keep to a 19-year old obsolete standard?

Comment: @DeiDei: Large software stacks are a barrier to upgrades. But yes, really one ought to move to at least C++03 now. I moved to C++11 two years ago. I'll schedule a move to C++17 sometime in 2020, and jump over C++14 entirely.

Comment: @DeiDei In my company we have to support modern and c++98

Comment: @Bathsheba Maybe, but I'm not really buying it. Turning on the C++14 compiler flag to recompile an old project will likely not break too many things, if any. At least not too many to fix in a reasonably short period of time.

Comment: @DeiDei some devices don't run with the new compilers

Comment: @slei The device has to compile? If not, then that ain't a reaso

Comment: well the new compilers aren't supported

Comment: at least we haven't figured out how to get c++11 working on ios 5 , which is the last supported version for ipad1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to do this in C++ 98, it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the old-fashioned `enum` metaprogramming trick:

```
template <typename ValueType, UInt32 size>
struct FixedArray
{
    enum {value = size};
    // All your other stuff, but ditch your GetCount() function.
};
```

Then,

```
FixedArray<int, 10> a;
FixedArray<int, a.value> b;
```

will compile under C++98.

Comment: is there also a way to keep the GetCount function?

Comment: You could have it `return value;` but you can't use it at compile-time. The `enum` approach pretty much gives you a `constexpr`.

Comment: `UInt32 GetCount() const { return value; }` will.

Comment: it still says "Non-type template argument of type 'UInt32' (aka 'unsigned int') is not an integral constant expression"

Comment: And when are you using the function?

Comment: somehwere e.g in a constructor.
FixedArray<int, 10> a;
FixedArray<int, a.GetCount()> b;

Comment: I've already told you you can't use a function in that context. You need to use `a.value` there, as I have written in the answer.

Comment: well yeah, seems to be the only solution

Comment: Yes, in C++98, your options are fairly limited. That doesn't make it a poor standard though. The absolutely beautiful version of Excel released in 
1997 was written using an earlier C++ than that.

Comment: puh, no idea why it still doesn't work now
Non-type template argument of type FixedArray<int, 10>::(anonymous enum at fixed_array.h:38:9)' is not an integral constant expression

Comment: I thought it works, but somehow it still doesn't work with the enum solution

Comment: it does with the c++11 compiler